# HP UFT no longer stopping at breakpoints for version 12.52 when using AOM

Tags: debugging, hp-uft

I am launching a test using AOM, but QTP UFT 12.52 (build 6851) is not stopping at my breakpoint. I'm facing the same issue with UFT 14. However, the same test was working in QTP 11.53.

I already tried reinstalling UFT, script debugger, registered the DLL, but to no avail. When I open UFT manually and put a breakpoint, then it will work as usual. But if the same test is opened using AOM, then I am facing the issue (not stopping at breakpoints) and also Play/Pause disappears. Also, the F9, F10, and F11 keys get disabled. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Same test was working in QTP 11.53, we are facing this issue after installing UFT 12.52, Facing the same issue in UFT 14 also..